# Crashlytics with Ant, cannot find symbol - missing jar

Tags: android, ant, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

My Android project uses vs-android, going through Ant to do the Java build.
As per the crashlytics/Ant documentation, I have set up custom_rules.xml to include crashlytics_build.xml, and the Ant output includes references to crashlytics as a result:

```
-post-build:
release:
android_rules.-pre-build:
crashlytics-init:
crashlytics-cleanup-resources:
crashlytics-pre-build:
crashlytics-init:
crashlytics-upload-deobs:
-pre-build:
crashlytics-generate-resources:
crashlytics-code-gen:
android_rules.-code-gen:
```

I then get the compile error:

```
error: package com.crashlytics.android does not exist
import com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics;
```

I don't know how it works but it appears that Crashlytics does not successfully inject its jar during the build process. I've located a copy of crashlytics-1.1.13.jar elsewhere on the internet, and when I add it to my libs folder it solves the problems. The App runs and it reports crashes.

However, this is not ideal, as I am not getting the updates the jar file (I have no idea if 1.1.13 is the latest or not), and I don't know whether there are other non-visible problems being caused by this also.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can find latest Jar via link, https://fabric.io/downloads/ant

Comment: That is the devtools jar, not the Android jar that gets injected at build time.

Comment: @Muzza, how have you resolved the issue with another import?

        error: package io.fabric.sdk.android does not exist
        import io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric;

I have the same issue. I've already found crashlytics-1.1.13.jar, but it solves only half of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reference with additional steps for those who will need to integrate an Android project that uses Ant with Crashlytics Fabric.

1. Use a Fabric plugin or usual instructions for Crashlytics integration. As a result you'll have:

   - ApiKey in AndroidManifest.xml
   - fabric.properties with with apiSecret in the root of a project
2. Download Fabric Ant Tasks from [here](https://fabric.io/downloads/ant)
3. Unzip/extract files to some directory (I've put it into crashlytics)
4. Download Fabric Crashlytics aar files from their [repository](https://maven.fabric.io/public) (I've downloaded all 5 libraries)
5. For each downloaded aar unarchive it take classes.jar, rename it to a better meaning and put into libs folder; I have following results:

[image]

6. Make sure your custom_rules.xml contains a line:

> ```
> <import file="crashlytics/crashlytics_build.xml"/>
> ```

**Notes:**

- My crashlytics/crashlytics.properties file contains lines for apiSecret & apiKey
- My App file is referenced in AndoroidManifest.xml in application block and overrides onCreate method:

> ```
> @Override
> public void onCreate() {
>     super.onCreate();
>     Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
> }
> ```

It works for me.